# Reading from .csv into a 1d array - perl

Tags: perl

I'm very new to perl. I'd like to read elements from a file and store them into a 1d array. For example,

```
1,6,1,0         
2,3,0,0         
3,2,0,0  

my $filename = $ARGV[0];
open(my $filehandle, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open $filename\n";
#
my @resultarray;
while(my $line = <$filehandle>){
    my @linearray = split("/n", $line);
}
while(foreach(@linearray){
    my @resultarray = split(",", $linearray);
}
```

Is this approach okay? If I'd like to read it into a 2d array, is it easier?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you have way more code than you need.  Within your `while` loop, you are already reading a line at a time -- just do all of your processing there.

Building the `@linearray` ahead of time buys you nothing in your example and will eat up unnecessary memory.  If you wanted to sort the data before pushing it to `@resultarray`, there may be some justification for doing it that way, but if you don't need to it's best to avoid the extra data structure.

```
my $filename = $ARGV[0];
open my $filehandle, '<', $filename or die "Could not open $filename\n";

my @resultarray;
while(<$filehandle>) {
    chomp;
    my @linearray = split /,/;

    ## What did you want to do here, just add them to @resultarray?

    push @resultarray, @linearray;
}
```

Bearing in mind, you could have done that in one step:

```
push @resultarray, split /,/;
```

Don't forget to close your filehandle.

```
close $filehandle;
```

All that said, if this is how you handle a comma-delimited file.  If you file is truly CSV (fields can have commas, return characters), then you really want to use `Text::CSV` which will handle all of that nastiness for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
open IN,$filename || die "$!";
my @res=();
while(defined($line=<IN>)){
    chomp($line);
    @info=split(/,/,$line);
    push(@res,[@info]);
}
print $res[1][1];
close IN;
```